# The difference between exchange method and execute method in spring rest template?

Tags: spring, rest

I have three questions!

**First.**

I am using the spring framework for sending the data through rest protocol.

```
restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl,HttpMethod.POST, request, listVo.getClass());

org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<? extends Object> responseType, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException
```

I used it without any problem, but I want to know the purpose of the parameter, responseType.
The client don't use response data, but just use response status code / msg. So, I sent some meaningless
String data instead. But the error thrown that they accept "null". So I sent a "null" String. not null.
Then, the error got rid of. But there was another problem. Right after the client received the data from the server and **paused for a long time.** Then next line of codes are executed. What is problem?

**Second**

I can't find any references that use execute method of Spring RestTemplate.

**Third**

Like the title, What is the difference between the exchange method and the execute method in spring rest template?

Thanks for your time and effort.
Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

exchange return type is `ResponseEntity<T>` while execute is `T`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from "[Pivotal Certified Spring Web Application Developer Exam](http://www.apress.com/9781484208090)" book

> The execute and exchange methods can be used for any type of REST calls
>
> The execute method can also be given a RequestCallback implementation as a parameter, which tells the RestTemplate what to do with the request before sending it to the server.